# Create user/item ranking sparse arrays in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have to generate sparse arrays filled with random values in [0,5] where 0 are missing values. The probability of the values has to change along the array. I though doing it this way:

```
a1 = np.random.choice(range(0,6),10,p=[0.3,0,0,0,0.3,0.4])
a2 = np.random.choice(range(0,6),10,p=[0.9,0.05,0.025,0.025,0,0])
a3 = np.random.choice(range(0,6),10,p=[0.95,0.05,0,0,0,0])
np.hstack([a1,a2,a3])

>>> array([4, 4, 5, 5, 0, 4, 5, 5, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

There is a cleaner and more united way for doing that?

Comment: What does `more united` mean in this context?

Comment: @cel It's hard to express it. It means using something like a moment-generating function (mgf) from any probability distribution that fills the array by itself (using a single function).

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
np.hstack([(np.random.choice(range(0,6),10,p=[0.3,0,0,0,0.3,0.4])), (np.random.choice(range(0,6),10,p=[0.9,0.05,0.025,0.025,0,0])),(np.random.choice(range(0,6),10,p=[0.95,0.05,0,0,0,0]))])
```

It doesn't really change anything, but it does look a bit cleaner and will not clutter up the namespace.

Comment: Isn't that the same, but everything in one single line? I don't see much of an improvement here.

Comment: Is there really any way it can be improved? He uses different arguments each time he calls `np.random.choice`, so it has to be called multiple times anyway, so what else can be improved?